# Angular blur on div or no called if in a dropdown

Tags: angular, onblur, onfocus

I have an input and when I type something, I display a div with different options (depending of what I type in the input). I want to hide the div when I blur the input.

```
<input type="text" (focus)="field.show_options = true" (blur)="field.show_options = false" />
<div *ngIf="field.show_options">
    <div *ngFor="let option of field.options" (click)="validate()">
       <span>{{ option.label }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I click anywhere, div disapears well. But if I click on an option, div disapears as well but the function from onclick (here it is validate()) is not called. How to manage that ?
I try to put onBlur event on the div, but don't working, even with tabindex="0". Any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>In angular, you should use `focusout` instead of `blur`:</strike>
You could try to use the `focusout` instead of `blur`.

```html
<input (focus)="field.show_options = true" 
       (focusout)="field.show_options = false"
       type="text">
```

In addition to that, it's important to notice that the `focusout` event runs first than the `click` event. So you need to force the `focusout` to wait a little bit before changes the value. You can do that with a method on the typescript side:

```js
_setFocus(focus: boolean) {
  if (!focus) {
    // the 200ms here is a matter of trial and error process: 
    //   very uncomfortable, but it's simple
    setTimeout(() => (this.field.show_options = focus), 200);
  } else {
    this.field.show_options = true;
  }
}
```

And, in your HTML:

```html
<input (focus)="_setFocus(true)" 
       (focusout)="_setFocus(false)"
       type="text">
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma614298856433166?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Personally I feel uncomfortable with a `setTimeout` in my code, but in this case, to avoid it, if possible, it would demand a more tricky setup.

Comment: Nop, not working. Same pb: when I click on one option, div disapears and click function is not called...

Comment: I suggest you double check your code. There's something else there preventing it from work. I've just put a link to a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma614298856433166?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) in my answer. I'm pretty sure it works.

Comment: I think you missunderstood the problem, I modify your code with my problematic: I want that the div of options still display if I click on it.
<div *ngIf="inputFocused" class="message" tabindex="0">
  {{inputFocused ? 'Click here to take focus out of input': 'Click on the input to put focus there'}}
</div>

Comment: Yeah, definitely misunderstood it! I'm sorry. I'm gonna give it another round.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The method is called, but... on your comment above you said that you want the div of options to not disappear if you click on it. Is that right? It'll demand a little bit of (more) code if so.

Comment: OK I will test that, thank you. In fact I want a feature like for example "Google Place Auto Complete" but with other options. And when I click option, the function is called and after the div is hidden. So I think your trick can work, I let you know.

Comment: @julianobrasil why should you use `focusout` instead of `blur` in Angular? Doesn't it depend on whether you want event bubbling or not?

Comment: You can use `blur` in some cases. The main difference is that `blur` doesn't bubble, so it demands you to capture the event in the exact element that lost focus. In the case of `focusout` the event will propagate to the parents so you could easily capture it in a wrapper `div`, for example, when one of its children emit a `focusout` (but not a `blur`). This is usually what people want. I'll make my answer clearer.

Comment: TBH, I don't remember why it wasn't working like it is described in the question :). Maybe it was something with angular by the time.